# settimeout call function for canvas timer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, settimeout

I wrote this code and I have problem with setTimeout call function for delay
This is a timer but setTimeout doesn't work every second
Why?

```
<head>
<script>
function timer(sec) {
    var c = document.getElementById("arcTimer");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0066CC";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100,100,75,-0.5*Math.PI,sec*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    if ( sec >= 1.5 ) {
        sec = -0.5;
    }
    setTimeout(timer(sec+0.03),1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="timer(-0.5);">

<canvas width="200" height="200" id="arcTimer" ></canvas>

</body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
setTimeout(timer(sec+0.03),1000);
```

...**calls** the `timer` function and passes its return value into `setTimeout`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** bar and passes its return value into `foo`. Since your `timer` function (implicitly) returns `undefined`, and `setTimeout` doesn't do anything when you pass it `undefined`, that calls `timer` (immediately) and then does nothing.

If you want to schedule a call to `timer` with `sec+0.03` as its argument, create a function that does that:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    timer(sec+0.03);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong: setTimeout(timer(sec+0.03),1000);
the first parameter is undefined, not a function.